# C - SQLite bind not working

Tags: c, sqlite

strI have this code that should insert into a SQLite3 database but both columns that I am trying to bind are inserting blank values. I have tried just using sprintf to place the values directly into the sql statement but that produced a segfault. I would appreciate any help I can get here.

```
   /* libsensordata.c */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sqlite3.h>

    int insert_data (char *sensor, double temp)
    {
            sqlite3 *db;
            char *err_msg = 0;
            sqlite3_stmt *res;

            int rc = sqlite3_open("ap.db", &db);

            if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                    sqlite3_close(db);

                    return -1;
            }

            char *sql = "insert INTO sensordata (sensor, temp, t, processed) values (@sensor,@temp,DateTime('now'),0)";

            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql, -1, &res, 0);

            if  ( rc == SQLITE_OK) {

                    int idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(res, "@sensor");
                    sqlite3_bind_text(res,idx,sensor,strlen(sensor),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(res, "@temp");
                    sqlite3_bind_double(res,idx,temp);

            }
            else {

                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                    sqlite3_close(db);
                    return -1;
            }

            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);

            if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

                    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

                    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
                    sqlite3_close(db);

                    return -1;
            }

            sqlite3_close(db);

            return 0;
    }

    /* Test database testdb.c */
    #include "libsensordata.h"

    int main()
    {
            insert_data("1234567890123456789012345",-17.0);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In `sqlite3_bind_text(res,idx,sensor,sizeof(sensor),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);` the `sizeof(sensor)` takes the size of a pointer (probably 4 or 8). Maybe you need `strlen(sensor) + 1`?

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [int sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt*);](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) instead of `sqlite3_exec` with an sql statement without the bound parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [sqlite3_exec](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) which simply execute the SQL statement

```
insert INTO 
    sensordata (sensor, temp, t, processed) 
    values (@sensor,@temp,DateTime('now'),0)`
```

which insert without any bound values to the statement (inserting empty values).

What you need is to call [sqlite3_step](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), which would execute the **prepared statement** ( `res` in your code ) passed as the argument.

You would have to replace this line :

```
 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);
```

with this one :

```
 rc = sqlite3_step(res);
```

for your code to perform the desired **insert**